# Replace the element with the searched value in an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having the following array of objects:

```
const input = [ {id: 3, data: {name: 'john'} },
                {id: 6, data: {name: 'mike'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'anna'} }
              ];
```

I want to write a method that recevies a new object, if the object's id is in the array, it replaces that one with the new one, otherwise it creates a new object.

For example, if the method receives this object: `{id: 1, data: {name: 'maria' }}`, it will add it to the array, so the array will look like:

```
const input = [ {id: 3, data: {name: 'john'} },
                {id: 6, data: {name: 'mike'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'anna'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'maria'} }
              ];
```

If it receives `{id: 3, data: {name: 'jack' }}` it should replace the object with id=3 so the result would be:

```
const input = [ {id: 3, data: {name: 'jack'} },
                {id: 6, data: {name: 'mike'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'anna'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'maria'} }
              ];
```

The code:

```
function doMagic(input, newObj) {
  if (input.some(el => el.id === newObj.id) {
    // replace it
  } else {
    // add the object to the array
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```js
function doMagic(input, newObj) {
 const i = input.findIndex(element => element.id === newObj.id);
  if (i > -1) input[i] = newObj; 
  else input.push(newObj);
}

const input = [ {id: 3, data: {name: 'jack'} },
                {id: 6, data: {name: 'mike'} },
                {id: 2, data: {name: 'anna'} }
              ];

newObj = {id: 1, data: {name: 'maria' }};
oldObj = {id: 3, data: {name: 'john' }}

doMagic(input, newObj);

console.log(input);

doMagic(input, oldObj);

console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function doMagic(input, newObj) {
    input.map((el, i, arr) => {
        if (input.some(el => el.id === newObj.id)) {
            input.splice(i, 1, newObj);
        } else {
            input.push(newObj);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check whether it contains desired object.
And if array contains object, then we can update it throug [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method. If no, then we just push this item to array.

```
const oneFunction = (arr, objToEdit) => {
  let existingObject = arr.find(f => f.id === objToEdit.id 
      && f.data.name !== objToEdit.name);

  if (existingObject) 
    Object.assign(existingObject, objToEdit);
  else 
    arr.push(objToEdit)  

  return arr;
}
```

An example:

```js
const input = 
[ 
  {id: 3, data: {name: 'john'} },
  {id: 6, data: {name: 'mike'} },
  {id: 2, data: {name: 'anna'} }
];

const oneFunction = (arr, objToEdit) => {
  let existingObject = arr.find(f => f.id === objToEdit.id && f.data.name !== objToEdit.name);

  if (existingObject) 
    Object.assign(existingObject, objToEdit);
  else 
    arr.push(objToEdit)  

  return arr;
}


let testObject = {id: 3, data: {name: 'john1'}};
console.log(oneFunction(input, testObject))
```